# ClickHouse deduplication using idempotency_id column

Tags: clickhouse

I have a Clickhouse table like this. We ingest rows data where the unique field is idempotency_id.

This is a sample. We can't use other columns for uniquness (like max(date) o max(clicks).

[image: 2023-12-13 20:00:00 97 5c77ed31-90ba-4b2b-b8a7-b5d22b8eb662 2023-12-18 21:00:00 92 83b13098-2afb-434c-89ff-1b5e0c58bdf0 2023-12-12 20:00:00 76 217f0432-081d-4b40-9a22-8cd6460943ab 2023-12-13 15:00:00 74 d7eaccd4-e489-42ea-ae22-2bbadc1785eb 2023-12-18 20:00:00 72 4fb98924-c5d1-4b07-9d1e-a371f866dc43]

I cannot use common [deduplication strategies](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/guides/developer/deduplication) like ReplacingMergeTree(idempotency_id) or CollapsingMergeTree(idempotency_id) because idempotency_id is a string.

At the moment I remove duplicate at query-time using PARTITION BY ROW_NUMER but it consume to memory and query stopped.

Comment: A String should still be usable as a key in a ReplacingMergeTree.  For performance reasons you also might consider converting the idempotency_id to a UUID data type and use that as a key.

Comment: I got this error: Code: 169. DB::Exception: The column idempotency_id cannot be used as a version column for storage ReplacingMergeTree because it is of type String (must be of an integer type or of type Date/DateTime/DateTime64). (BAD_TYPE_OF_FIELD) (version 23.9.2.47608 (official build))

Comment: A version column is used to indicate which row should be considered the "correct" value for the table's primary key column (or columns).  So you should have something like an insert timestamp column in your table, and use that column as the "version", and ClickHouse will keep the "latest" row for your idempotency_id.

Comment: So do I just need to create a table where the "idempotency_id" is within the GROUP BY column list and add a inserted_at:datetime field and use it and version columun of ReplacingMergeTree ?

Comment: In the ORDER BY (or PRIMARY KEY), not GROUP BY, but yes, that is how to get started.

Comment: I created a tmp table with SharedReplacingMergeTree and ORDER BY list contains idempotency_id. I inserted rows from old table but I still find duplicates in idempotency_id. Why ?

Comment: The ReplacingMergeTree will remove duplicates with the same PRIMARY KEY (which is often the same as the ORDER BY).  If your primary key contains more than one column and the combination is not unique, the ReplacingMergeTree will not consider that a duplicate.

In addition deduplication is not immediate, but happens when parts are merged.  To ensure a query result with no duplicates, you must add FINAL to your query.  There are several articles about deduplication with RMT with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
    `idempotency_id` UUID,
    
     ...other fields    

    version UInt32 DEFAULT now() 
)
ENGINE = ReplacingMergeTree
PRIMARY KEY (idempotency_id)
ORDER BY (idempotency_id, ....)
```

Then when I want to be sure to remove duplicates I run

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE my_table
```